# Can't connect to remote endpoint using self-signed cert from Web Api core app on Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi, self-signed

When I try to connect to a remote endpoint from my dockerized web api core app, I'm getting the following error: `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

When running this same app outside of Docker, it works as expected. I believe the issue is that our organization uses self-signed certs. The complete chain is loaded on my local machine, but I can't get it installed on Docker so the web api app will recognize it.

After loading the certs in my Dockerfile (see details below), I am able to connect to the remote site with openssl and curl successfully from my Dockerfile:

```
RUN openssl s_client -connect REMOTE.ENDPOINT:443 -servername REMOTE.ENDPOINT -verify_hostname REMOTE.ENDPOINT
...snip...
Verification: OK
...snip...
RUN curl --verbose https://REMOTE.ENDPOINT
...snip...
SSL certificate verify ok.
```

Note that these openssl and curl calls are the last things in my Dockerfile so I expected everything would be setup for my app to see and use the certs as well.

Here's how I'm adding the self-signed certs to the docker image in the Dockerfile

```
ADD localEc.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localEc.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localEc.crt && update-ca-certificates
```

When the app runs, I've verified my cert is not in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and my cert file is not in `/etc/ssl/certs`. Although I don't think it should be necessary, I have tried copying the certs to the image directly:

```
COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY ["/etc/ssl/certs", "/etc/ssl/certs"]
```

What am I missing?

I do know that I can override the ssl validation process to allow this cert, but I'd rather fix the root issue (and avoid all the discussion that would be caused by the workaround `<g>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I didn't fully understand how the staged docker build process works. It seems that when debugging, Visual Studio only uses the first stage of the dockerfile and I was adding the certificates in the last stage. [This article](https://blog.ehn.nu/2020/02/how-visual-studio-2019-supports-containerized-applications/) clarified the Docker build process.